# Criar projeto JPA sem o persistence.xml?

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

Criei um projeto com Swing e JPA e está funcionando bem, agora quero retirar o arquivo `persistence.xml` e criar uma classe para que trabalhe no lugar dele. Estou pesquisando alguma maneira de fazer isso e encontrei nas documentações um exemplo de como fazer [aqui](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/). Mas nao estou conseguindo fazer funcionar, sempre que executo o projeto retorna o erro: `Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named iguanaauto`.

Como resolver esse problema ?

Estou tentando assim.

```
public class JPAUtils {  
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;

    /** retorna o entitymanager */
    public static EntityManager getEntityManager(){
        //emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("iguanaauto");        
        EntityManager em = getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        return em;
    }

    private static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(){
        if(emf == null){
            Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
            properties.put("javax.persistence.provider", "org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider");                       
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/iguanaauto_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true");
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "root");
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "");
            properties.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation", "create-or-extend-tables");
            properties.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode", "database");
            properties.put("eclipselink.logging.level", "FINE");

            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("iguanaauto", properties);            
        }
        return emf;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não tem como se livrar totalmente do persistence.xml, porque você precisa ter pelo menos o nome de uma unidade de persistência declarado:

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="nomeDaPU">
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

O resto das propriedades você pode criar da forma como estava fazendo que vai funcionar.